# How to set docker command --log.level=DEBUG in a marathon deployment file?

Tags: docker, mesos, marathon

reading at this `docker-compose` file : (Source: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guides/docker-compose/acme-dns/#setup)

```
version: "3.3"
services:
  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.1.0"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
```

How can I set `--log.level=DEBUG` command in this [marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/) deployment file:

```
{
  "id": "/whoami",
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 256.0,
  "instances": 1,
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "traefik:v2.1.0",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Is that what you are looking for ? https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html#command-vs-args

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need to add `"args": ["--log.level=DEBUG"]` to your JSON.

```
{
  "id": "/whoami",
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 256.0,
  "instances": 1,
  "args": ["--log.level=DEBUG"],
  "container": {
    "type": "DOCKER",
    "docker": {
      "image": "traefik:v2.1.0",
      "network": "BRIDGE",
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "containerPort": 80,
          "protocol": "tcp"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```